# iopl() fails intermittently

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, system-calls

I am working on a hardware device, where I have to do some GPIO operations.
At the start of my program, I invoke `iopl(3)`. The executable is not `root` owned, but has capabilities set - `cap_sys_rawio+eip`. Though this works most of the times
sometimes the process fails with:

```
iopl: Operation not permitted
```

Is the capability insufficient ? I cannot run the program as `root`.
The device is running `Ubuntu 14.04.2`. `dmesg` / `syslogs` are not giving
any hints!

More details:

The start of my `main` has this:

```
if (iopl(3) != 0) {
    perror("iopl");
    assert(!"Failed to set privilege!");
}
```

Though this works most of the times, sometimes on the hardware platform
(Intel Atom based), this fails with `perror` printing `iopl: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Care to provide the code to reproduce the problem? Also, what architecture are you running?

Comment: My program main has: `if (iopl(3) != 0) { perror("iopl"); }`. I am not able to reproduce the issue at will! :( it happens some times and I am not getting any clue as to why `iopl` failed. This is intel Atom (`Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  C2558  @ 2.40GHz`) CPU. If you need any more details, please let me know.

Comment: Add the architecture and the code to your question, including a `main()` and includes, to make the question more complete. One more think to look at would be `strace`. Capture its output and compare the error case to the non-error case. In particular, whether there are symptoms before the `iopl()`-call. Other than that, I'm at a loss, too.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sure, if this happens again, will `strace` it

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that you cannot run the program as root, I am guessing if you have tried:

```
 chmod u+s /usr/bin/xinit
```

or if you have root access,

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/xinit
```

If no setuid has been set (considering running without sudo --since you have already root access)

`sudo chown root $prefix/Xorg`

`sudo chmod u+s $prefix/Xorg`

Comment: Yes, the executable already has capabilities set, so it does not have to run as root

Comment: Is Xorg setuid to root?

Comment: I am not using Xorg at all. This is my own application, for which I am doing setcap and not suid root.